# Apache webserver error on startup

Tags: apache

I just switch to Apache webserver and I receive an error

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network
>   address/port) is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to
>   address 0.0.0.0:443 no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs

That is what I have got after running httpd from commandline. I reset my apache documentRoot as well as server's listening port to one that is free to use already, I have no idea about this error with port 443, is it something about SSL ?

**UPDATE**
I am using XP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying and pasting your exact error into google gave a couple of answers:

- https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress

Port 443 seems to already be in use.  Possibly by your old server.  One of the three covered errors in the official apache wiki above is:

**Address is already in use**

> Something else is already using the port in question.
>
> Run one of the following commands to check if a running process is
>   holding the port needed by apache open.
>
> ```
> On Linux/Unix run
> $>  netstat -plant
> $> # or
> $> sudo lsof -i:80
>
> On Windows run
> $>  netstat -ano
>
> On Mac OS X / FreeBSD run
> $> netstat -Wan |grep 80
> $> # or, to get the pid
> $> sudo lsof -i:80
> ```
>
> Once you see these results, you can choose to kill the program in
>   question, or change the port that Apache uses.
>
> If Apache (httpd, apache2, etc) is the application listening on these
>   ports, but you can't stop it using your normal procedure, someone may
>   have deleted the servers PidFile. The PidFile records the process ID
>   of the parent process and is how most scripts test to see if Apache is
>   running. You can manually stop the server by determining the PID of
>   the parent process and sending it a SIGTERM.

Comment: The above link is not working, it says page not found

Answer (score 32):

For Windows XP

```
netstat -ano
```

Find the process id that is using port 443, and kill it using task manager

For me it was IIS using the port.

Comment: +1, `netstat` pointed me to the culprit: in my case it was Skype. Had to go to Options > Advanced > Connection, then uncheck *Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections*

Answer (score 7):

For me it was having multiple directives of `Listen 443` in my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file. Even though `netstat` and/or `ps` showed nothing for 443, it was still trying to listen multiple times, which in turn threw that error.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you already have apache running.   Use nestat to figure out which process is using 443 and kill it.

`netstat -tulpn | grep :443`

Then

`kill PROCESS_ID`

Where `PROCESS_ID` is the number of the process that is shown when you the netstat command (example: `kill 12345`).

After that try starting apache again.

Comment: If you're using XP SP3 go to your Task Manager.  Click Processes then View Processes By All Users.   Locate apache or httpd on the list and End all of them.  Then go to `Start` -> `Run` and type `services.msc`.  Locate apache/httpd and Start it from there.

Comment: Since you switched to Apache, also make sure in services.msc that IIS isn't running.

Comment: Yes I did it also but I have got an popup error message that says "Windows could not start the Apache2.2 on Local COmputer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-MS service, contact service vendor and refer to service specific error code 1"

Comment: @Mackintoast, if it works now and is because of this answer, then be a nice guy and accept seanbreeden's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found on my system (Win7) that Skype had taken over the port that Apache was trying to use.  In the new version of Skype I haven't yet found the checkbox to uncheck so that Skype doesn't use it (there was one in a previous version).  Quitting Skype enabled Apache to start.

Comment: I just found how to do it - https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop?frompage=search&q=port+80&fromSearchFirstPage=false

Comment: if you are using windows os and believe that skype is not the suspect, then you might want to check the task manager and check the "Show processes from all users" and make sure that there is NO entry for httpd.exe. Otherwise, end its process. That solves my problem.

Comment: Yes exactly, Quit the skype and here you go!

Answer (score 0):

port 443 is for SSL. Seems you miss the rights to use that privileged port. Privileged ports are those with numbers below 1024.

Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using XP SP3 and I set my apache to listen to port 81

Answer (score 0):

Probably something else is already using port 443 and therefore Apache is unable to use it, do you want to use SSL actually ?

Comment: At my level of web coding, SSL is useless. Could you provide me a working solution ? I also updated my OP for a detail of my current OS

Comment: If you don't want to use SSL por 443 for your coding, remove the vhost directives with SSL on it's name and set any 443 string back to 80. You can comment lines preceding by #