# Apache is shutdown in xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Problem in starting Apache service only. MySQL is working fine.

This is the error when i run Apache as admin from cmd:

> C:\Windows\system32>c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe (OS 10048)Only one
>   usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   [::]:443

---

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network
>   address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not
>   bind to address 0.0.0.0: 443 AH00451: no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down

Comment: do a netstat -na to see if port 443 is already being used

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241409/apache-webserver-error-on-startup